# How to achieved an type-token ratio dictionary in NLTK ordered by fileids?

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, nltk, typetoken

So I'm writing a program that will help me find the type-to-token ratio of all the the inaugural speeches of the presidents, and save it in the dictionary `ttr`. But for comparison's sake, I need the dictionary created at the end to go in the order of the year, so that I can use it to plot a graph, to find out whether the vocabulary richness has increased or decreased, how do I do that? the `for pres in president` part seems to have messed up the order of `fileids`.

```
from nltk.corpus import inaugural 

ttr = {}    
president = inaugural.fileids()

for pres in president:
    tokens = inaugural.words(pres)
    numtokens = len(tokens)
    types = sorted(set(tokens))
    numtypes = len(types)
    ttr[pres] = float(numtypes)/numtokens

print ttr
```

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered.  It doesn't matter how you create the dictionary; if it's a plain dictionary, you can't rely on the order.  You could use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you want to retain insertion order, or you could use some kind of list structure instead of a dictionary.

Comment: why would order be important?

Comment: because im analysing the vocabulary richness over the years and plotting them on a graph after this part, so the order of the fileids (the years) matter. So I'm guessing you suggest using a list structure instead? but Idk how to make a list that goes like ["fileid1", ttr1, "fileid2", ttr2...]

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand your question, but:

> I need the dictionary created at the end to go in the order of the year,

Dictionaries are not ordered.  They represent a pairing of values with keys.  You can, however, control the order you process the entries.  For example:

```
d = { ... }
for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
     print (key, value)
```

Here I used the function `sorted()` to sort the entries of the dictionary and process them in order.

Comment: idk why python says too many values to unpack when i did this

Comment: should be `sorted(d.items())`.

Answer (score 0):

To improve your code, make use of `collections.Counter` or `nltk.FreqDist`, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html and http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html

Then use the length of key of the dictionary as your unique vocabulary size. And a dict comprehension would have done the trick.

Try:

```
from collections import Counter
from nltk.corpus import inaugural

presidents = inaugural.fileids()

ttr = {}
for pres in presidents:
    freqdist = Counter(inaugural.words(pres))
    vocabsize = float(sum(freqdist.values())
    freqdist =Counter({k:v/numtokens for k,v in freqdist.items()})
    ttr[pres] = freqdist

for pres in ttr:
    print pres, ttr[pres].most_common(2)
```

[out]:

```
1917-Wilson.txt [(u'the', 0.16029143897996356), (u'of', 0.1384335154826958)]
1837-VanBuren.txt [(u'the', 0.18209408194233687), (u'of', 0.15022761760242792)]
1861-Lincoln.txt [(u'the', 0.22263450834879406), (u',', 0.18089053803339517)]
1849-Taylor.txt [(u'the', 0.19238476953907815), (u'of', 0.12424849699398798)]
```

The problem is that the code above only describe the means to normalize counts from the corpus. What you get from the code in your example from the question is **NOT** real type-token ratio.

A type-token ratio would have to involve lowercasing all words and also their POS tag, so try:

```
from collections import Counter

from nltk.corpus import inaugural
from nltk import pos_tag

presidents = inaugural.fileids()

ttr = {}
for pres in presidents:
    _ttr = Counter()
    # Keep track of the counter so that you don't have to iterate the corpus 
    # again to recount the numtokens
    numtokens = 0.0 
    for word, pos in pos_tag(inaugural.words(pres)):
        wordtype = word.lower()+"#"+pos # This is a type
        _ttr[wordtype] += 1
        numtokens += 1
    _ttr = Counter({k:v/numtokens for k,v in _ttr.items()})
    ttr[pres] = _ttr

for pres in ttr:
    print pres, ttr[pres].most_common(2)
```

Then you realized that punctuation are taking up different types so you have to flatten all punctuations:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation

from nltk.corpus import inaugural
from nltk import pos_tag

presidents = inaugural.fileids()

ttr = {}
for pres in presidents:
    _ttr = Counter()
    # Keep track of the counter so that you don't have to iterate the corpus 
    # again to recount the numtokens
    numtokens = 0.0 
    for word, pos in pos_tag(inaugural.words(pres)):
        if word in punctuation:
            pos = "PUNCT#PUNCT"
        wordtype = word.lower()+"#"+pos # This is a type
        _ttr[wordtype] += 1
        numtokens += 1
    _ttr = Counter({k:v/numtokens for k,v in _ttr.items()})
    ttr[pres] = _ttr

for pres in ttr:
    print pres, ttr[pres].most_common(2)
```

Since you're keeping in a dict, order doesn't matter, so to retrieve the ttr dictionary in order, simply sort it:

```
for pres in sorted(ttr):
    print pres, ttr[pres].most_common(2)
```

[out]:

```
1789-Washington.txt [(u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.08), (u'the#DT', 0.08)]
1793-Washington.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.09), (u'of#IN', 0.08)]
1797-Adams.txt [(u'of#IN', 0.08), (u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.07)]
1801-Jefferson.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.08), (u'of#IN', 0.07)]
1805-Jefferson.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.06), (u'on#IN', 0.05)]
1809-Madison.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.09), (u'of#IN', 0.08)]
1813-Madison.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.09), (u'of#IN', 0.06)]
1817-Monroe.txt [(u'of#IN', 0.08), (u'the#DT', 0.07)]
1821-Monroe.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.08), (u'which#WDT', 0.05)]
1825-Adams.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.09), (u'of#IN', 0.06)]
1829-Jackson.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.09), (u'to#TO', 0.06)]
1833-Jackson.txt [(u'of#IN', 0.07), (u'the#DT', 0.07)]
1837-VanBuren.txt [(u'of#IN', 0.07), (u'the#DT', 0.07)]
1841-Harrison.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.08), (u'to#TO', 0.07)]
1845-Polk.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.08), (u'of#IN', 0.06)]
1849-Taylor.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.11), (u'to#TO', 0.05)]
1853-Pierce.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.06), (u'to#TO', 0.06)]
1857-Buchanan.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.09), (u'of#IN', 0.06)]
1861-Lincoln.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.09), (u'of#IN', 0.05)]
1865-Lincoln.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.09), (u'of#IN', 0.06)]
1869-Grant.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.1), (u'of#IN', 0.08)]
1873-Grant.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.09), (u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.07)]
1877-Hayes.txt [(u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.1), (u'the#DT', 0.08)]
1881-Garfield.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.07), (u'of#IN', 0.05)]
1885-Cleveland.txt [(u'of#IN', 0.09), (u'the#DT', 0.08)]
1889-Harrison.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.18), (u'of#IN', 0.07)]
1893-Cleveland.txt [(u'of#IN', 0.06), (u'the#DT', 0.06)]
1897-McKinley.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.09), (u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.07)]
1901-McKinley.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.08), (u'to#TO', 0.06)]
1905-Roosevelt.txt [(u'of#IN', 0.06), (u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.05)]
1909-Taft.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.1), (u'of#IN', 0.08)]
1913-Wilson.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.08), (u'.#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.06)]
1917-Wilson.txt [(u'of#IN', 0.06), (u'our#PRP$', 0.06)]
1921-Harding.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.07), (u'and#CC', 0.06)]
1925-Coolidge.txt [(u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.05), (u'the#DT', 0.05)]
1929-Hoover.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.07), (u'of#IN', 0.06)]
1933-Roosevelt.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.06), (u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.05)]
1937-Roosevelt.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.08), (u'to#TO', 0.06)]
1941-Roosevelt.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.09), (u'of#IN', 0.06)]
1945-Roosevelt.txt [(u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.07), (u'of#IN', 0.07)]
1949-Truman.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.08), (u'.#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.06)]
1953-Eisenhower.txt [(u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.06), (u'the#DT', 0.06)]
1957-Eisenhower.txt [(u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.15), (u'.#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.06)]
1961-Kennedy.txt [(u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.11), (u'.#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.05)]
1965-Johnson.txt [(u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.08), (u'.#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.07)]
1969-Nixon.txt [(u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.08), (u'.#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.06)]
1973-Nixon.txt [(u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.08), (u'.#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.06)]
1977-Carter.txt [(u'to#TO', 0.06), (u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.05)]
1981-Reagan.txt [(u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.11), (u'of#IN', 0.04)]
1985-Reagan.txt [(u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.11), (u'of#IN', 0.03)]
1989-Bush.txt [(u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.12), (u'and#CC', 0.04)]
1993-Clinton.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.1), (u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.08)]
1997-Clinton.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.06), (u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.05)]
2001-Bush.txt [(u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.07), (u'and#CC', 0.06)]
2005-Bush.txt [(u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.13), (u'the#DT', 0.06)]
2009-Obama.txt [(u'the#DT', 0.08), (u',#PUNCT#PUNCT', 0.04)]
```

Comment: POS tagging the corpus takes time. A server would take minutes but your laptop might take hours, so `Keep Calm and Drink Coffee`